# What does "had long" mean?

Tags: expressions

I've encountered with this sentence:

> Vera was reluctant to mention that her uncle **had long** since departed.

What does "had long" mean here?

Comment: Is it a book? can you provide the source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Had long" doesn't mean anything in particular. "Long since" is what you need to look at. It's an adverbial phrase that modifies "departed" and means that it had been a *long* time *since* her uncle departed.

Comment: You are right, thank you so much.